# Infinite loop with do function

Tags: c++, loops, infinite

I'm super new with C++ and programming in general and I need some help. I don't understand why is it infinite looping when the computer has guessed my number. Currently I've put at the end a break function. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
// Computer guesses number

#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0))); // Generates random number

    int myNumber; // My number.
    int computersNumber = 0; 
    int tries = 0;
    int highest = 100; // Highest number the computer has put.
    int lowest = 1; // Lowest number the computer has put.

    cout << "\tHello, in this game the computer will try to find your number.\n\n";
    cout << "Please insert your number ( 1 - 100 ): ";
    cin >> myNumber; // My number, that the computer is going to guess.

    while (myNumber <= 0 || myNumber >= 101) // Checks if user has inputed a legal number.
    {
        cout << "You entered an illegal number. Please type a new one.\n";
        cin >> myNumber; // If user made an illegal choice it asks to input a new one.
    } 

    do
    {
        int computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;
        ++tries; // adds +1 every time computer guesses wrong number.

        if (myNumber > computersNumber)
        {
            cout << "The computer guessed: " << computersNumber << "\n";
            lowest = computersNumber + 1;
        }
        else if (myNumber < computersNumber)
        {
            cout << "The computer guessed: " << computersNumber << "\n";
            highest = computersNumber - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Computer guessed your number in " << tries << " tries.\n";
            break; // infinite loop if this wasn't here.
        }

    } while (myNumber != computersNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you step through that loop with your debugger?

Comment: Off topic: `// Generates random number` seeds the random number generator, actually.

Comment: Don't know if this matters much for this assignment, but you will also get an infinite loop if the user types in a value that can't be converted to an integer. Eg: Please insert your number ( 1 - 100 ):  FOO! `cin` will be placed in an error state and refuse to read further input until the the error is cleared, and since it is never cleared the loop asking for input will never receive new input and spin forever.

Comment: You also have a bug where if `highest` and `lowest` converge, you get a divide by zero trying to compute the random guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared another variable named `computersNumber` inside your loop. the `computersNumber` used in the while statement is another variable you've declared in the main function.

You can fix this issue by using the same variable in your loop:

Change this line

```
int computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;
```

and remove the `int` keyword.

```
computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;
```

you can read more about variable scopes in the following link:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_variable_scope.htm

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that you re-declare `computersNumber` inside the do-while loop.  This creates a new, local instance of the variable that everything within the do-while uses, but the conditional in the `while()` statement itself is still referencing the `computersNumber` variable declared within the `main()` method, which isn't being changed because `int computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;` tells C++ to make a new variable inside the do-while loop, not modify the original variable inside `main`.

To fix it, change this line:

```
int computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;
```

To this:

```
computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;
```

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a new variable inside the `do` loop:
`int computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;`

This definition is inside the loop scope and is invisible outside of the `do { }` block.

Your `while (myNumber != computersNumber);` condition is checking against the `int computersNumber = 0;` definition from outside the loop, which is always 0.

The fix would be to reuse the existing variable inside the loop instead of creating a new one, so remove the `int` from the following line:

`int computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;`

and instead use

`computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;`.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `computersNumber` in two spots. So you have one set to zero, `int computersNumber = 0;` and in the other spot you are assigning a random number to `int computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;`.

One that is set to zero is the one you are checking, because the one that has been set to a random number only has a scope of the each iteration it has been set in. Meaning the outside the loop `computersNumber` is always zero and inside the loop a new `computersNumber` is being created with a random value. So as long as `myNumber` isn't set to zero, will have an infinite loop.

To fix this just remove `int` from `int computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;`, making it `computersNumber = rand() % (highest - lowest) + lowest;` and each time you loop you will set `computersNumber` to a random value and if that random value matches `myNumber` it will break the loop.